# mysql query message save into table or external file

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mysql-workbench

I have multiple store procedures to do the ETL work in mysql. Normally, it is running on the server for over night.

inside the store procedures there are multiple update statement like

`update table1 set column1=3 when column2 = 4`

if there any way, I can keep the mysql workbench result like
`Rows matched: 100 Changed: 50 Warnings: 0`

for each statement I run either into mysql table or external file?

prefer mysql native method. if not, any python I could possible use?

Answer (score 1):

"Rows changed" can be retrieved with `ROW_COUNT()` function.

"Rows matched" needs in a trick with user-defined variable usage.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, val INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,4);
> ```

Now we want to perform `UPDATE test SET val = 3 WHERE id = 1;` and count the amounts.

> ```
> UPDATE test
> -- add user-defined variable for matched rows counting
> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @matched := 0 ) init_variable
> -- increment matched rows counter (this expression is always TRUE)
> SET val = CASE WHEN @matched := @matched + 1 
> -- update the column
>                THEN 3
>                END
> WHERE id = 1;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @matched matched, ROW_COUNT() changed;
> ```
>
> ```
> matched | changed
> ------: | ------:
>       3 |       2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2ccd3f4deff4b1e667c5113bef809d6)*

If more than one column should be updated in a query then only one expression must be accompanied with the counter increment.